# Map a Pandas Series with duplicate keys to a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Env: Python 3.9.6, Pandas 1.3.5**

---

I have a DataFrame and a Series like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"C1" : ["A", "B", "C", "D"]})
sr = pd.Series(data  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               index = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "D"])
"""
[DataFrame]
   C1
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D

[Series]
A    1
A    2
B    3
C    4
D    5
"""
```

What I tried,

```
df["C2"] = df["C1"].map(sr)
```

But InvalidIndexError occurred because the series has duplicate keys ("A").
***pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects***

Is there any method to make DF like below?

```
   C1 C2
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  3
3  C  4
4  D  5

or

   C1 C2
0  A  1    
1  B  3
2  C  4
3  D  5
4  A  2
```

Row indices do not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was heavily edited and now has a very different meaning.

You want a simple `merge`:

```
df.merge(sr.rename('C2'),
         left_on='C1', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  C1  C2
0  A   1
0  A   2
1  B   3
2  C   4
3  D   5
```

###### old answer

First, I don't reproduce your issue (tested with 3M rows on pandas 1.3.5).

Then why do you use slicing and not `map`? This would have the advantage of systematically outputting the correct number of rows (NaN if the key is absent):

Example:

```
sr = pd.Series({10:"A", 13:"B", 16:"C", 18:"D"})
df = pd.DataFrame({"C1":np.random.randint(10, 20, size=3000000)})
df['C2'] = df['C1'].map(sr)
print(df.head())
```

output:

```
   C1   C2
0  10    A
1  18    D
2  10    A
3  13    B
4  15  NaN
```

Comment: I didn't know about "map". However "map" let me know that there were duplicate keys in the series. Thus I edited the question a lot. Your answer guided me anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @Sangeun OK, then you want a `merge`